# App Engine logging.properties: customize Date format for lazy-evaluation Log

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, logging, lazy-evaluation, date-formatting

I have a very simple code

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloAppEngine.class.getName());
logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is now: {0}", new Date());
```

defined inside a (Maven based) Google App Engine project.

The output of this log is

```
giu 10, 2017 6:03:10 PM it.log.HelloAppEngine doGet
INFO: This is now: 10/06/17 18.03
```

with the default Date format. I want to customize the Date format with my own.

I don't really know where this configuration need to be placed, I think that can be inside the `logging.properties` file, but I'm unable to find the proper cofniguration

Which is the proper way to customize the Date format provided by the lazy-evaluted log message?

I found the relevant code inside the `java.text.MessageFormat` class.
[image]

which is triggered to format the `Date` object

It does not seem that is accessing to an external configuration in order to format the date, it uses a fixed `DateFormat.SHORT` format. Maybe there is a way to provide a custom formatter which will override that entire implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to customize the Date format with my own.
>
> I don't really know where this configuration need to be placed, I think that can be inside the logging.properties file, but I'm unable to find the proper configuration

You have to include the date format in the log string as described in the [`java.text.MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class level docs.  As stated there you can use any of the [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) patterns.

For example, you can use the `DateFormat` constants:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is now: {0,date,long} at {0,time,full}", new Date());
```

Otherwise, you can use a pattern:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is now: {0,date,EEE, MMM dd HH:mm:ss:S ZZZ yyyy}", new Date());
```

If you use [localization in your logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) you can replace the messages with a shorter key and leave the date format patterns in your ResourceBundle.